# How do I unset all of the select boxes for pages

Tags: wp-admin, plugins

I am using WooCommerce and need to recreate the default pages. The answer given is

1. Go to WooCommerce > Pages and unset all of the select boxes for the
   pages (including the shop base option).
2. Deactivate the WooCommerce plugin
3. Activate the WooCommerce plugin

But how do I actually unset all of the select boxes for pages - not sure what it means

Comment: Click, until the check mark vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly.

But I think you should click on 'x' in every select on this page.

When you do it, this select box will have no selected value any more (it will only contain placeholder saying "Select a page...").

Just look at attached image. I marked this 'x' with an arrow on it!

[Click on every 'x' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwLTK.png).